# Can anyone source this Arizal?

Tags: tefilla, arizal

I have heard that Rav Chaim Vital brings down from the Arizal to say “v’ahavta l’reiacha kamocha” before davening. Where can this be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in פתורא דאבא [Inyan Birchas Hashachar, Hakdama, number 2](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9544&st=&pgnum=11):

[image]

Comment: That looks like a compilation of his practices. The real source is Pri Eitz Chaim Shaar HaAsiya Chapter 1

Answer (score 1):

[Magen Avraham (46:1)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95) cites Arizal that one should accept the mitzvah of loving others before Shacharis.

> קודם בואו לבית הכנסת יאמר ואני ברוב חסדך וכו' ובכניסתו יאמר בבית אלהים נהלך
> ברגש (כתבים) **קודם תפלת שחרית יקבל עליו מ"ע של ואהבת לרעך כמוך**
> [הכוונות]:

The source of this is R' Chaim Vital (Shaar Hakavanos) who writes to say this before reciting the Parshas HaAkeidah:

> **קודם שהאדם יסדר תפילתו בבית הכנסת** **מפרשת העקידה ואילך**, צריך שיקבל עליו
> מצות ואהבת  לרעך כמוך, ויכוון לאהוב כל אחד מבני ישראל כנפשו, כי על ידי
> זה תעלה תפילתו כלולה מכל תפילות ישראל ותוכל לעלות למעלה ולעשות פרי.
> ובפרט אהבת החברים העוסקים בתורת ביחד, צריך כל א' וא' לכלול עצמו כאילו
> הוא אבבר אחד מן החברים שלו, ובפרט אם יש להאדם ידיעה והשגה לדעת ולהכיר
> לחבירו בבחינת הנשמה, ואם יש איזה חבר מהם בצרה צריכים כולם לשתף עצמם
> בצערו או מחמת חולי או מחמת בנים ח"ו, ויתפללו עליו. וכן בכל תפילותיו
> וצרכיו ודבריו ישתף את חבירו עמו.

It is noteworthy, that elsewhere R' Chaim Vital (Hakdamah l'Chochma Haemes) writes that this should be before entering the synagogue.

> **קודם שיכנס** ישים אל לבו מצוות עשה ואהבת לרעך כמוך **ואח"כ יכנס**